# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf - low performance on very large lists (20,000+ items)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm working on a feature that has a dual list select box on the view layer. There are some 20,000 available items to be brought to the select and it is taking a very long time to load the page and every interaction (typing on a filter box, selecting item from the list, etc.) takes a very long time to process.

Is there a way to speed it up?

My form is:

```
<form role="form" action="#" th:object="${pojo}" th:action="@{/contract/assignStructure}" method="post">
    <select multiple="multiple" id="selectedStructures" name="selectedStructures" class="form-control">
        <option th:each="structure : ${allStructures}" 
                th:value="${structure.getId()}"
                th:selected="${assignedStructures.contains(structure)}"
                th:text="${structure.description}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" th:text="#{gen.save}">Save</button>
    </div>  
</form>
```

And the javascript section that handles this list is, so far:

```
$('#selectedStructures').bootstrapDualListbox();
```

The problem, I believe is in my Structure pojo whose attributes are defined as:

```
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Contract contract;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Term> terms;
```

Possibly, the performance issue has to do with the `FetchType`.

The business logic is that one or more `Structure` are part of a `Contract` and may have one or `Term`.

Mapping on `Contract` is:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Structure> structures;
```

And mapping on `Term` is:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Structure structure;
```

Is this right? Is there a way to improve the performance of a method retrieving a `List<Structure> findAll()` by adjusting the annotations?

Comment: I recommend you to implement pagination on DAO and presentation layer. No matter what improvements you can make, it can be slow to be rendered depending on the number of records. Take a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html

Comment: Thymeleaf is highly unlikely to be the bottleneck in this case, I suspect that several thousand database queries are being executed to load the page. The first thing to do is turn on Hibernate's SQL output to get an idea of the magnitude of the problem. To reduce the number of queries I would recommend looking at using Spring Data JPA, it offers several fetch control mechanisms including `entity graphs` and `query projections` which can significantly reduce the number of queries needed to load data.

Comment: you need to implement query using fetch command to avoid too many query

Comment: First thing you must do is profile (using VisualVM) to identify bottlenecks instead of presuming where the slow code is without any proof. ("The problem, I believe...", "Possibly, the performance issue...")